# REST parsing enum fails for string

Tags: xml, rest, java-ee-7

a REST URL is allowing access via a GET to an url which contains an enum value as a query parameter. If I send a request which contains the name of the enum variable it works but if I use a string value it doesn't.

Example: access via `[...]cars/1?myEnum=CLIENT` works but `[...]cars/1?myEnum=Client` doesn't. Why?

```
@XmlType
@XmlEnum
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public enum MyEnum {

    @XmlEnumValue("Client")
    CLIENT("Client"),
    @XmlEnumValue("Server")
    SERVER("Server");

    @Getter
    private final String value;

    public static MyEnum fromValue(String v) {
        for (MyEnum c : MyEnum.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }
}
```

The client

```
@GET
@Path("cars/{myPathParam}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getCars( //
        @PathParam("myPathParam") final String myPathParam,
        @QueryParam("myEnum") final MyEnum myEnum) {
    return "someValue";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the name of the method. In my example above it is `fromValue`. However, according to the spec (JSR339, Chapter 3.2 Fields and Bean Properties) it should be `valueOf` or `fromString`:

> Types that have a static method named `valueOf` or `fromString` with a
>   single `String` argument that return an instance of the type. If both
>   methods are present then `valueOf` MUST be used unless the type is an
>   enum in which case `fromString` MUST be used.